# Hi I am new to Python and I was coding this program that I have a problem with

Tags: python

1. I want to break the code when the enemy has 0 health. Where do I break the code?
2. How do I get the two while loops to keep repeating until the enemy's health reaches 0? Do I nest the 2nd while loop in the first while loop?

```
p1.hp = 100
e1.hp = 100


g = False
while g == False:
  g = True
  chanceR = chance[randint(0,1)]
  choiceR = choice[randint(0,1)]
  print("Your turn!")
  p1c = input("Choose an option: [attack] or [block] ")
  if p1c == "attack":
    if choiceR == "attack" and chanceR == "succcess":
      print("Enemy countered your attack!")
    elif choiceR == "attack" and chanceR == "fail":
      print("Attack sucessful! Enemy loses 10HP!")
      e1.hp -= 10
      print("Enemy's health:", e1.hp)
    elif choiceR == "block" and chanceR == "success":
      print("Enemy blocked your attack!")
    elif choiceR == "block" and chanceR == "fail":
      print("Enemy failed to block! Enemy loses 10HP!")
      e1.hp -= 10
      print("Enemy's health:", e1.hp)
  elif p1c == "block":
    if choiceR == "attack" and chanceR == "success":
      print("Attack blocked successfully!")
    elif choiceR == "attack" and chanceR == "fail":
     print("Enemy failed to attack. Nothing happens")
    elif choiceR == "block":
     print("Enemy blocks. Nothing happens")
  else:
    print("That is not a valid input. Please try again")
    g = False



while g == True: 
  print("Enemy's turn")
  chanceRp = chance[randint(0,1)]
  choiceRp = choice[randint(0,1)]
  chanceRe = chance[randint(0,1)]
  choiceRe = choice[randint(0,1)]
  if choiceRe == "attack" and chanceRe == "success": 
    if choiceRp == "attack" and chanceRp == "success":
      print("You successfully countered the enemy's attack!")
    elif choiceRp == "attack" and chanceRp == "fail":
      print("Enemy successfully attacked you! You lose 10 HP!")
      p1.hp -= 10
      print("Your health:", p1.hp)
    elif choiceRp == "block" and chanceRp == "success":
      print("You successfully blocked the enemy's attack!")
    elif choiceRp == "block" and chanceRp == "fail":
      print("You failed to block the enemy's attack! You lose 10HP!")
      p1.hp -= 10
      print("Enemy's health:", p1.hp) 
  elif choiceRe == "attack" and chanceRe == "fail":
    if choiceRp == "attack" and chanceRe == "success":
      print("You successfully attacked the enemy! Enemy loses 10HP!")
      e1.hp -= 10
      print("Enemy's health:", e1.hp)
    elif choiceRp == "attack" and chanceRp == "fail":
      print("Both the enemy and you failed to attack! Nothing happens!")
    elif choiceRp == "block" and chanceRp == "success":
      print("Enemy failed to attack! Nothing happens!")
    elif choiceRp == "block" and chanceRp == "fail":
     print("Enemy failed to attack! Nothing happens!")
  elif choiceRe == "block" and chanceRe == "success":
    if choiceRp == "attack" and chanceRp == "success":
      print("Enemy successfully blocked your attack!")
    elif choiceRp == "attack" and chanceRp == "fail":
      print("You failed to attack!")
    elif choiceRp == "block" and chanceRp == "success":
      print("Both the enemy and you blocked! Nothing happens!")
    elif choiceRp == "block" and chanceRp == "fail":
     print("Both the enemy and you blocked! Nothing happens!")
  elif choiceRe == "block" and chanceRe == "fail":
    if choiceRp == "attack" and chanceRp == "success":
      print("Enemy failed to block! Enemy loses 10HP!")
      e1.hp -= 10
      print("Enemy's health:", e1.hp)
    elif choiceRp == "attack" and chanceRp == "fail":
      print("You failed to attack!")
    elif choiceRp == "block" and chanceRp == "success":
      print("Both the enemy and you blocked! Nothing happens!")
    elif choiceRp == "block" and chanceRp == "fail":
     print("Both the enemy and you blocked! Nothing happens!")
  g = False
```

g means game
p means player
e means enemy

This code basically shows the possible out come for both the player and the enemy on each of their turns

```
chance = ["success", "fail"]

choice = ["attack", "block"]
```

here is the chance and choice variables for the code

I'm really new to this so if you could help me, I would really appreciate it. Thank You :)

Comment: Please see how to create a [mcve]

Comment: Maybe wrap both  with a `while e1.hp > 0 or p1.hp > 0:`

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick note before I find the hp part: don't repeat yourself!  Here you define two classes that are exactly the same, and you initialize them with a value that you throw away:

```
class Enemy:
  def __init__(self, health):
   self.hp = health

class Player:
  def __init__(self,health):
    self.hp = health

p1 = Player("player 1")
e1 = Enemy("Orc")

p1.hp = 100
e1.hp = 100
```

Instead you could do:

```
class Character:
    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self.name = name
        self.hp = 100

player = Character("player 1")
enemy = Character("Orc")
```

Now both `player` and `enemy` have 100 hp, and they have `name` attributes that are whatever you passed in (in your previous code, the names you passed in just got overwritten because you were passing them as the `health` argument).

Another thing to watch out for is that by using string literals to represent everything, you open yourself up to bugs where you typo the string:

```
if choiceR == "attack" and chanceR == "succcess":
```

Note the misspelling in `"succcess"`!  This check will just quietly always be `False`.  A better option is to use `Enum`s, which will give you errors (either at runtime or when you run type checking tools) if you try to use them in obviously incorrect ways.

To keep the attack/counterattack sequence going, yes, you'll need to put everything in another loop.  This will be easier to read if you define a function for each "turn" (that contain their own loops) and then run those functions in an outer loop, like:

```
while True:
    player_turn()
    if game_over():
        break
    enemy_turn()
    if game_over():
        break
```

Another way to do this would be with exceptions, which have the nice property of automatically breaking out of whatever context they happen in:

```
try:
    while True:
        player_turn()
        enemy_turn()
except GameOverException as e:
    print(e)
```

With those functions implemented, it might all together look something like:

```
from enum import Enum, auto
import random
from typing import Dict, Tuple


class Action(Enum):
    ATTACK = "attack"
    BLOCK = "block"


class Character:
    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self.name = name
        self.hp = 100


class GameOverException(Exception):
    pass


def get_player_action() -> Action:
    """Prompt the user for an action."""
    while True:
        try:
            return Action(input(
                "Choose an option: [attack] or [block] "
            ))
        except ValueError:
            print("That is not a valid input. Please try again")


def player_turn(player: Character, enemy: Character) -> None:
    """Take the player's turn.  Raises GameOverException if game over."""
    print("Your turn!")
    player_action = get_player_action()
    damage = 0
    enemy_action = random.choice(list(Action))
    enemy_success = random.choice([True, False])
    if player_action == Action.ATTACK:
        if enemy_action == Action.ATTACK:
            if enemy_success:
                print("Enemy countered your attack!")
            else:
                damage = 10
                print(f"Attack successful! Enemy loses {damage} HP!")
        elif enemy_action == Action.BLOCK:
            if enemy_success:
                print("Enemy blocked your attack!")
            else:
                damage = 10
                print(f"Enemy failed to block! Enemy loses {damage} HP!")
    elif player_action == Action.BLOCK:
        if enemy_action == Action.ATTACK:
            if enemy_success:
                print("Attack blocked successfully!")
            else:
                print("Enemy failed to attack. Nothing happens")
        elif enemy_action == Action.BLOCK:
            print("Enemy blocks. Nothing happens")

    if damage > 0:
        enemy.hp -= damage
        print(f"Enemy's health: {enemy.hp}")
    if enemy.hp <= 0:
        raise GameOverException(f"{enemy.name} is dead.  You win!")


def enemy_turn(player: Character, enemy: Character) -> None:
    """Enemy's turn.  Raises GameOverException if game over."""
    print("Enemy's turn")
    enemy_action = random.choice(list(Action))
    enemy_success = random.choice([True, False])
    player_action = random.choice(list(Action))
    player_success = random.choice([True, False])
    # Rather than have a bunch of deeply nested if/elifs, let's just make
    # a table of all the possible (message, enemy_damage, player_damage)
    # results based on (enemy_action, success, player_action, success).
    results: Dict[Tuple[Action, bool, Action, bool], Tuple[str, int, int]] = {
        # Successful enemy attack results
        (Action.ATTACK, True, Action.ATTACK, True):
            ("You successfully countered the enemy's attack", 0, 0),
        (Action.ATTACK, True, Action.ATTACK, False):
            ("Enemy successfully attacked you!  You lose 10 HP!", 0, 10),
        (Action.ATTACK, True, Action.BLOCK, True):
            ("You successfully blocked the enemy's attack!", 0, 0),
        (Action.ATTACK, True, Action.BLOCK, False):
            ("You failed to block!  You lose 10 HP!", 0, 10),
        # Failed enemy attack results
        (Action.ATTACK, False, Action.ATTACK, True):
            ("You successfully attacked the enemy! Enemy loses 10HP!", 10, 0),
        (Action.ATTACK, False, Action.ATTACK, False):
            ("You both failed to attack! Nothing happens!", 0, 0),
        (Action.ATTACK, False, Action.BLOCK, True):
            ("Enemy failed to attack! Nothing happens!", 0, 0),
        (Action.ATTACK, False, Action.BLOCK, False):
            ("Enemy failed to attack! Nothing happens!", 0, 0),
        # Successful enemy block results
        (Action.BLOCK, True, Action.ATTACK, True):
            ("Enemy successfully blocked your attack!", 0, 0),
        (Action.BLOCK, True, Action.ATTACK, False):
            ("You failed to attack!", 0, 0),
        (Action.BLOCK, True, Action.BLOCK, True):
            ("Both the enemy and you blocked! Nothing happens!", 0, 0),
        (Action.BLOCK, True, Action.BLOCK, False):
            ("Both the enemy and you blocked! Nothing happens!", 0, 0),
        # Failed enemy block results
        (Action.BLOCK, False, Action.ATTACK, True):
            ("Enemy failed to block! Enemy loses 10HP!", 10, 0),
        (Action.BLOCK, False, Action.ATTACK, False):
            ("You failed to attack!", 0, 0),
        (Action.BLOCK, False, Action.BLOCK, True):
            ("Both the enemy and you blocked! Nothing happens!", 0, 0),
        (Action.BLOCK, False, Action.BLOCK, False):
            ("Both the enemy and you blocked! Nothing happens!", 0, 0),
    }
    message, enemy_damage, player_damage = results[
        (enemy_action, enemy_success, player_action, player_success)
    ]
    print(message)
    if enemy_damage > 0:
        enemy.hp -= enemy_damage
        print(f"Enemy's health: {enemy.hp}")
        if enemy.hp <= 0:
            raise GameOverException(f"{enemy.name} is dead.  You win!")
    if player_damage > 0:
        player.hp -= player_damage
        print(f"Your health: {player.hp}")
        if player.hp <= 0:
            raise GameOverException(f"You have been slain.  You lose!")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    player = Character("player 1")
    enemy = Character("Orc")
    try:
        while True:
            player_turn(player, enemy)
            enemy_turn(player, enemy)
    except GameOverException as game_over:
        print(game_over)
```

Comment: Oh thanks I understood everything clearly. So in short, I can define the possible outcomes for the player and enemy separately as functions, and put the functions in a while loop. And also define a function for when it's game over for either the player or the enemy

Comment: Yes; breaking it out into functions will help keep things separated so you don't lose track of where you are when you're in the middle of a giant loop with fifty different if/elif statements (which is a whole other problem).

Answer (score 0):

Your two separate turns are part of the same loop. The way it's structured now, the game will run AAAAAAA and then BBBBBBB instead of ABABABABABABAB.

Think of the while condition instead as what is actually occurring - a fight.

```
fighting = True
while fighting:
  # Player turn
  # Enemy turn
```

The player turn and enemy turn are the sequence of events that occur in order in each loop of the fight. Now, your event tree of if's and elifs is a bit disorganized, and as such, far more verbose than it needs to be. Beyond that, there's little difference in the way that one turn and the other turn are coded, so you could write a single function to define a turn, passing in which player has which role in that turn, but that's outside the scope here. For the break, think of it like this:

```
fighting = True
while fighting:
  # P1 turn
  # Get input and random
  # Change HP
  # If after the change, the HP is <= 0:
    fighting = False
    break
...
enter code here
```

Comment: Thank you! I understood everything and I will try to apply it into my code!